# How to reconstruct a response to Amazon lex from AWS lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I have set up a bot in lex console that collects data from users such as the product/service that they are interested in and email-ID, Phone number etc. Now every time a visitor interacts with the bot I would want to receive an email with chat conversations.

I also created a lambda function that is triggered by lex fulfilment but i get this error on bot ui **An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response: Received invalid response from Lambda: Can not construct instance of IntentResponse: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value**

As per the documentation I have reconstructed a response and returning it.

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)

    var1 = '''dialogAction": {
    "type": "close",
    "fulfillmentState": "fulfilled",
    "message": {
      "contentType": "PlainText or SSML or CustomPayload",
      "content": "Message to convey to the user. For example, What size pizza would you like?"
    },
    }
    }'''
    return(var1)
```

And here is what the error looks like:-

```
An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response: Received invalid response from Lambda: Can not construct instance of IntentResponse: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('"dialogAction": { "type": "close", "fulfillmentState": "fulfilled", "message": { "contentType": "PlainText or SSML or CustomPayload", "content": "Message to convey to the user. For example, What size pizza would you like?" }, } }') at [Source: "\"dialogAction\": {\n \"type\": \"close\",\n \"fulfillmentState\": \"fulfilled\",\n \"message\": {\n \"contentType\": \"PlainText or SSML or CustomPayload\",\n \"content\": \"Message to convey to the user. For example, What size pizza would you like?\"\n },\n }\n }"; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrectly passing the response as a string. And by using the triple quotation marks `'''`, it is adding the line breaks `\n` which you can see in the error source, and you don't want those.

So try this, simply return the response as an object. I believe the callback function will automatically convert to JSON before delivering to Lex.

```
 var1 = {
    dialogAction": {
         "type": "close",
         "fulfillmentState": "fulfilled",
         "message": {
               "contentType": "PlainText or SSML or CustomPayload",
               "content": "Message to convey to the user. For example, What size pizza would you like?"
         },
    }
}
return var1
```